# Быстрая и грубая оценка количества значащих двоичных цифр в заданном неотрицательном числе

Tags: алгоритм, численные-методы

Собственно, знаю о решении в лоб - двоичном логарифме, и итерационной его реализации для целого результата: D сдвигов вправо, пока заданное число N > 0:

```
int D = 0;
while (N > 0) {
    N = N >> 1;
    D++;
}
```

Но существует ли какой-либо хак, чтобы получить результат быстрее, чем сдвигами в цикле? (возможно, пожертвовав точностью)

Comment: Кстати, для более грубой оценки достаточно сдвигать не на 1 бит, а сразу на несколько, например >>4 если нужна точность до 4 бит.

Comment: а вы уверены что ключевая проблема performance приложения именно в операции побитового сдвига?

Comment: @insolor, остроумная идея, спасибо

Answer (score 6):

Количество нулевых бит в 64-разрядном целом

```
// adapted from Hacker's Delight
int clzll(uint64_t x) {
  int n;

  if (x == 0) return(64);
  n = 0;
  if (x <= 0x00000000FFFFFFFFL) {n = n + 32; x = x << 32;}
  if (x <= 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFFL) {n = n + 16; x = x << 16;}
  if (x <= 0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFL) {n = n + 8; x = x << 8;}
  if (x <= 0x0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL) {n = n + 4; x = x << 4;}
  if (x <= 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL) {n = n + 2; x = x << 2;}
  if (x <= 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL) {n = n + 1;}
  return n;
}
```

Дальше подсчитать несложно.

Comment: Посмотрел, очень интересная книга.

Answer (score 5):

Зачем терять точность? Ниже точная оценка числа единичных битов.

```
scanf("%u", &x);

x = (x & 0x55555555) + ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
x = (x & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((x >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F);
x = (x & 0x00FF00FF) + ((x >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF);
x = (x & 0x0000FFFF) + ((x >>16) & 0x0000FFFF);

printf("%d\n", x);
```

или

```
scanf("%u", &x);

x = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555); 
x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333); 
x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F; 
x = x + (x >> 8); 
x = x + (x >> 16); 
x &= 0x0000003F;

printf("%d\n", x);
```

А, я, кажется, неверно понял вопрос, имелось в виду сколько разрядов, считая от левой единицы? Вот код, дающий количество ведущих нулей, 32 - n даст количество значащих разрядов.

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned int n = 1;

scanf("%u", &x);

if (x == 0) return(32);

if ((x >> 16) == 0) {n = n + 16; x = x <<16;}
if ((x >> 24) == 0) {n = n + 8; x = x << 8;}
if ((x >> 28) == 0) {n = n + 4; x = x << 4;}
if ((x >> 30) == 0) {n = n + 2; x = x << 2;}
n = n - (x >> 31);

printf("%d\n", n);
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать таблицу степеней 2 и проводить по ней бинарный поиск:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int table[32] = {
    0x00000001, 0x00000002, 0x00000004, 0x00000008,
    0x00000010, 0x00000020, 0x00000040, 0x00000080,
    0x00000100, 0x00000200, 0x00000400, 0x00000800,
    0x00001000, 0x00002000, 0x00004000, 0x00008000,
    0x00010000, 0x00020000, 0x00040000, 0x00080000,
    0x00100000, 0x00200000, 0x00400000, 0x00800000,
    0x01000000, 0x02000000, 0x04000000, 0x08000000,
    0x10000000, 0x20000000, 0x40000000, 0x80000000
};

int bits(unsigned int n) {
    int i=0, j=32, k=16;
    while(i<k) {
        if(n<table[k]) j = k;
        else i = k;
        k = (i+j)>>1;
    }
    return j;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=0x100;i++)
        printf("0x%08X %d\n",i,bits(i));
    return 0;
}
```

**P.S.** А можно сделать бинарным поиском, но без таблицы :

```
int bits(unsigned int n) {
    int i=0, j=32, k=16;
    while(i<k) {
        if(n<(1<<k)) j = k;
        else i = k;
        k = (i+j)>>1;
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что на реальной машине (с учетом конвейеризации, предсказания переходов, опережающего исполнения команд и т.п. в современном CPU) от двоичного поиска в массиве из 32 элементов будет выигрыш по сравнению с линейным поиском.

Comment: @avp, я тоже сомневаюсь)

Comment: Экие вы прагматики.

Answer (score 4):

У многих процессоров есть подобная инструкция. Но писать под каждый процессор свою реализацию не очень удобно.

В gcc [есть](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) встроенные функции __builtin_clz..., которые в случае поддержки процессора, компилируются в соответствующие инструкции, иначе gcc сам генерит какой-то код.

В MSVS тоже [есть нечто подобное](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384809.aspx), __lzcnt..., но в документации сказано, что разработчик должен проверить поддержку этой операции процессором, иначе результат вызова непредсказуем.

Comment: Спасибо за `__builtin_clz`, правда, бегло пролистав over4000 страниц [руководства Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) инструкции, непосредственно возвращающей количество ведущих нулей не нашел.

Comment: Нашел [интересную статью](http://locklessinc.com/articles/next_pow2/), где в том числе обсуждается ассемблерный код `__builtin_clz`.

Comment: Я помню в VAX/11 было инструкция ffs (find first set) если не вру с мнемоникой. Насколько помню она  искала в памяти (максимальную длину области памяти не помню).

Comment: Вот здесь расписана специфика по процам и крестокомпиляторам en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_leading_zeros

Answer (score 2):

Исчо один вариант. С длинным сдвигом. Результат от 0 (для аргумента 0) до 32.

```
static int m[] = {0xffff0000, 0xff00, 0xf0, 0xC, 2};
int bits(unsigned long a) {
    int n=0;
    int k=16;
    int *m1 = m;
    while(k) {
        if(a&*m1++) {
            n += k;
            a >>= k;
        }
        k >>= 1;
    }
    return a?n+1:n; // (0..31) => (1..32) для a != 0
}
```

Любители сишных трюков могут перенести сдвиг k в заголовок while для большей кучерявости (тогда нач. значение k будет 32)

Answer (score 2):

Странно, что никто не предложил использовать массив в качестве хэша:

```
int f(unsigned int n)
{
  static const int bitsByNum[16] = {1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4};

  int removed = 0;
  if (n > (unsigned int)0xFFFF)
  {
    removed += 16;
    n >>= 16;
  }
  if (n > (unsigned int)0xFF)
  {
    removed += 8;
    n >>= 8;
  }
  if (n > (unsigned int)0xF)
  {
    removed += 4;
    n >>= 4;
  }
  return removed + bitsByNum[n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще так попробовать, правда сомневаюсь, что это даст выиграш производительности, разве что на числах очень большой разрядности:

Предположим у вас есть N-битное число Y.
делаем xor между старшими N/2 битами числа и N/2 младшими (повторяем необходимое количество раз)
результат каждой итерации имеет точность 0.5-1.0 от реального значения (т.е точность 2х будет 0.25 - 1, 0,0625 - 1).

Можно подобрать необходимое количество итераций, а что более важно можно будет прогнать на реальных данных даную функцию и сравнивать ее точность с точностью исходного алгоритма (приведенного в теле вопроса)

Answer (score -1):

А если так (на Java):

```
int d=Integer.toBinaryString(N).length();
```

Comment: Офигеть, очень быстрый способ =)

Comment: Конечно медленнее побитовой сдвижки, но зато коротко и ясно

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что заметно лаконичнее простого цикла со сдвигами. Кстати, зачем метку про биты убрали? Задачка-то больше ориентирована на специфику реализации вычислений, чем на математические методы.

Comment: @Barmaley, вы вопрос читали?
"Но существует ли какой-либо хак, чтобы получить результат быстрее, чем сдвигами в цикле? "